# I am trying to install php on my mac os but getting errors as per memory

Tags: php

$ php composer.phar install

i keep getting all sorts of errors

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268435456 bytes) in phar:///Users/namdionwuachu/repos/notejam/cakephp/notejam/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

> Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.Namdis-MBP:notejam namdionNNNNamdis-MBP:notejam namdionwuachu$  COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=2G php composer.phar update
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- cakephp/cakephp 3.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.9.0-RC2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.9.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.9.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.8.9 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.8.8 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.8.7 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.8.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your

I need your help thanks Namdi

Comment: `brew install php70-intl` change version number to match the version of PHP that you installed

Comment: how do I change the version number ? what version number is this

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not just install LAMPP or similar? I have found installing PHP on my Mac not worth the effort, especially since it has it's own default installation. It's just a pain. If you can use LAMPP or similar, you will probably have better results.

Comment: the `70` stands for `7.0` so if you aer using PHP 7.4 then do `brew install php74-intl`